# Is the old man from episode 2 the same person we see later?

Tags: bubuki-buranki

In episode 2, an old man who is present when Oubu first ascends to the surface with Azuma as its heart mentions that he saw Oubu when it razed Ueno 24 years prior.

[image: episode 2, 9:08]

Later, in episode 24, Azuma runs into a "stinking drunk" in the park:

[image: episode 24, 15:35]

Are these the same people?

Answer (score 1):

I'm inclined to say that these are the same person. In episodes 2 and 24, [Nishimura Taisuke](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=66807) is credited as "homeless man". Assuming conservation of detail, it probably makes sense for the guy in episode 24 to be the same person as the guy in episode 2.